# Advice request on poetic translation

Tags: traducción

I am a Spanish beginner.

Can

1. "earthly aroma" be translated to *"aroma terrenal"*?
2. "summit to sea" be translated to *"cima al mar"*?
3. "sea to summit" be translated to *"mar al nieve"*?

Yo quiero demostrar un impresión poética y rústica en mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

- The word *terrenal* has somewhat of a religious or metaphysical connotation. It means 'earthly', yes -- as the opposite of 'Heavenly' with a capital H. If by "earthly aroma" you mean something like that smell that fills the country after it rains, you probably meant "earthy aroma" and in that case I'd use *"aroma **terroso**"* or just *"aroma **de tierra**"* or *"olor **a tierra**"*.
- The word 'summit' can mean *cima* as a noun, but it can also be a verb. I need the context for both "summit to sea" and "sea to summit" for a proper translation. What I can tell you is ***nieve* is feminine**, so *"mar al nieve"* is grammatically incorrect: it should be *"mar a la nieve"* (not saying it's a good translation, just that *del* is incorrect there).

I'll be waiting for your update.

Answer (score 0):

Impresión poética y rústica al mismo tiempo:

1. "earthly aroma": olor a tierra
2. "summit to sea": desde el pico de la montaña hasta el mar (but this doesn't sound poetic because of rhythm problems)
3. "sea to summit": desde el mar hasta la zona nevada (from the sea to the snowy area)